# Why does "issue" have a negative connotation in the US?

Tags: american-english, ambiguity

Why does "*issue*" have a negative connotation in the US?

I have used *issue* as a synonym of *tema* in Spanish.

Comment: Words tend to take on new connotations over time.  How this happens is anyone's guess.  The negative connotation associated with "issue" is relatively new, I suspect.  "Issue" is a sort of code, or shorthand, for mental problems, neuroses, phobias, hang-ups, baggage--all negative concepts.  When someone observes, "Oh, him . . ., he has issues!" you can be pretty sure the observer is implying a negative criticism.  I predict the use of the word "issues" in this way will fall out of favor soon, only to be replaced with a different code word.  And so it goes.

Comment: I'm trying to visualise various synomimes.

Comment: It may be a fact but you have not substantiated your assumption that *issue* has negative connotations, perhaps in the US. What are the sources? Or is it only your observation?

Comment: Include the query in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any distinction between British and American English when it comes to the word *issue*. But it is probably worth noting here that *issue* can have various meanings, depending on the context. Some examples:

- In a continued series of booklets such as **newspapers or magazines** *issue* refers to a specific volume, e.g. *The New York Times issue 6/14/2013*.
- When you have a **topic/concern/question** to discuss with someone, you approach her with your *issue*.
- In case you are in **dispute** with someone, you have an *issue* with him.

So you see that *issue* can mean *topic* in some contexts (2nd example) and have a negative connotation in others (3rd example).

Getting from the 2nd to the 3rd example by saying that the concern may be controversial justifies the (partially) negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a synonym of *tema* ("topic"), but you must know that a better synonym could be *trouble* or *problem*, something that isn't really okay, a controversial topic maybe, but not any topic. For that reason the word *issue* has a negative connotation and it doesn't happen just in US, it's a common thing for English speakers.

Comment: I really appreciate if the person how vote down, tell me why, it's really important for me in order to improve. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - took me a while to type this . . . While "issue" *can* have a negative connotation in certain contexts, I would not say that the OP must know that "trouble" or "problem" is a better synonym . . . just two other synonyms that in *other* specific contexts, might be better suited for the OP's meaning.  The OP did not give us the context other than a similarly meaning Spanish word which you translated as "topic".  "Topic" is as good a synonym for "issue" as the others, given the correct context.

Comment: "synonymic" -- an adjective, isn't it?

Comment: This answer hasn't explained anything. It's circular reasoning. You simply say that *issue* has a negative connotation because it has a negative connotation. That is not helpful at all. −1 from me as well. That *issue* means "trouble, problem" can be looked up in any dictionary, so that is not the question here. The question here is, *why* does it mean that.